# Ordered starting and waiting for containers

Tags: junit, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, testcontainers

I have two containers in my tests using `@Testcontainers` with Junit5, a `Kafka` and a `KafkaConnect`.

```
@Container
private final KafkaContainer kafka = new KafkaContainer()
        .withNetwork(network)
        .withNetworkAliases("kafka");

@Container
private final GenericContainer KafkaConnect = 
        new GenericContainer("confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest")
        .withEnv("CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "kafka:9092")
        .withEnv("CONNECT_REST_PORT", 8083)
        .withNetwork(network)
        ...
```

When I execute the tests, I find an error because Kafka Connect service in `kafkaConnect` is not is not started correctly (mapped port 8083 is not listening). It is because `kafkaConnect` is started before `kafka` and when the `kafka:9092` url is reached during the `kafkaConnect` execution no response is obtained since `kafka` is not running yet. 
Then, I have tried to pospone the `kafkaConnect` start up in order to wait for `kafka` to ensure `kafka:9092` availability.

I have tried different approach to do this but I did not fix the problem.
I tried to add some configurations.

`startupTimeout`. As far as I know, this config does not pospone the start operation. It just increase the period to check if the container is started.

```
.withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(240, SECONDS))
```

I also tried some configurations for `waitingFor`, such as timeout-based, which,a s expected, produces the same result than `withStartupTimeout`

```
.waitingFor(Wait.defaultWaitStrategy().withStartupTimeout(...))
```

or port-based, which does not solve my issue because it does not point to `kafka` container but `kafkaConnect`.

```
.waitingFor(Wait.forHttp("http://kafka:9092"))
```

I have also tried to add a number of startup attempts but it does not solve the issue because the `kafkaConnect` is relaunch some times but always before `kafka`.

As a solution I removed `@Container` of `kafkaConnect` declaration in order to use manage manually its lifecycle, so I added the explicit starting to testcase, see below

```
@Test
test() {
    kafkaConnect.start();
    ...
}
```

This ensure `kafkaConnect` is started after `kafka`. However, I did not find a solution to define the order during the container definition, by means of strategies, policies or something similar, in order to add dependencies between containers and to avoid a imperative and manual lifecycle management.

is it possible?

Comment: I guess Compose can be useful here but I am find a solution from the container declarations

Answer (score 1):

```java
import org.junit.rules.RuleChain;

// @Container <-- Remove annotation.
private final KafkaContainer kafka = new KafkaContainer()...;

// @Container <-- Remove annotation.
private final GenericContainer kafkaConnect = 
        new GenericContainer("confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest")
        .withEnv("CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "kafka:9092")
        ...;

// Start the containers in the correct order.  Prevents
// "Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started"
// error.
@Rule
public final RuleChain chain = 
    RuleChain
    // Started first.
    .outerRule(kafka)
    // Started later.
    .around(kafkaConnect);
```